Build Maui Windows stage gets error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string
I have a Maui application that builds fine on local machine (Release or Debug) but when push to GitHub repo and then the Azure pipeline runs. The windows stage build step fails with the following error:
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(226,5): error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string: '..'. [D:\a\1\s\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0]

Workload updates are available. Run `dotnet workload list` for more information.

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Build Windows MAUI app

This has been working in Azure pipeline but something has changed but not sure what.
Can someone give me some help as to why I have this issue?
I have verified that version was correct as far as I can tell.

What is the detailed value of the invalid NuGet version string? How did you configure the build pipeline in Azure DevOps? Provide the detailed YAML of your build pipeline in your question.
